# Stored Procedure as Source in Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure which will have rows as output but when I try in the Data Flow Source I'm getting error message

`DF-SYS-01` at Source `'source1'`:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.`

My Source is Query option and I'm trying to execute

`"EXEC [UVREP].spFeedsProduct 'HH',-2"`

Can't I use Stored Procedure as Source in Data Flow ? I'm able to do the same in Copy Data Activity it works fine? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've run a few experiments and replicated your results, both with and without parameters. I honestly didn't know this limitation existed. You may need to consider extracting the data to a staging location (like CSV file or another table in SQL).

Answer (score 0):

ADF Data Flow source can take queries or UDFs, but not sprocs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation

As Joel mentioned in comments, you can use an ADF Stored Proc activity in the pipeline to execute the sproc before your data flow and store the results in a table or staging file (Parquet/CSV) for the data flow source to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MarkKromer and JoelCochran.

Instead of Stored Procedure now I modified using Views. Using a pipeline with lookup and Data Flow inside the for each loop. I have to copy like 12 tables to three different sinks.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm also getting following error when source didn't return any rows {
    "errorCode": "4501",
    "message": "Failed to fetch execution state: '', please retry. If the problem persists, please contact Azure Support",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "dataflow1",
    "details": []
}

Comment: Views are fine. It is recommended that when you use a Data Flow activity inside a pipeline ForEach that you set it to sequential and use a TTL on the Azure IR for the data flow. I'm not sure what that error is. You may need to create a ticket from the Azure portal on it.

Comment: My copy activity finishing with stored procedure as source, not sequential in a minute and 30 seconds approximately a minute and half almost every time. When I change that using DATAFLOW inside the same for loop it's taking close to 5 minutes and even with TTL turned on. So we decided to leave it copy activity. Unless Data Flow with 5 minutes is cheaper. I tried 8 cores with compute optimized. Since I'm copying 13 tables I think Copy Activity in the Pipeline is much cheaper than DataFlow.

Comment: If you are using a TTL in the Azure IR that is associated with your data flow, then your startup latency should be 2 mins, not 5 mins. Make sure you have set the same Azure IR in your data flow activity that you have configured the TTL.

Comment: @markKromer Not Startup latency. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to tell, my entire process with pipeline without dataflow with copy activity finishes in less than 2 minutes but with Data Flow it's double the time any where between 5 minutes or so.

With Pipeline I have to do two copy activities for two different destinations(sinks) but with data flow one source and two sinks that's the advantage. But time wise even with two pipelines we are saving like a minute and half. Do you still want to create a ticket so someone can look if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I've been experiencing the "Failed to fetch execution state: ''" problem myself. It is a known issue that the ADF engineers are working on - it shouldn't be related to the source having no rows. The recommendation at present is to add a Retry to your Data Flow. It doesn't solve the problem entirely, but should reduce the frequency.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I have question for you and @MarkKromer I was under impression data flow moving from one source to two sinks will be faster with data flow so I don’t have two copy activities but my testing shows copy activity is faster than data flow I tried even the TSL ; putting all 13 tables in single data flow ;passed from a for each using sequential all didn’t even came close to the copy activity timing.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the startup latency. If you look at the monitoring display on each of those data flow activity interactions, you'll see a 1-2 min startup time just to acquire the JIT compute resources inside the data flow. Copy Activity uses hot VMs, so there is no spin-up time incurred. So, Copy Activity always has a 1-2 min headstart on end-to-end timing.

Comment: Is there any plans to reduce these latency? Our management is questioning why we should convert to Data Flow and spend more money for our Data Warehouse Migration.

Comment: Latency is due to JIT ephemeral cluster creation. It would be much more costly for you to keep a Spark cluster (Databricks in this case) running 24x7. Databricks is constantly improving those start-up times and I've seen some improvements in that area recently.